# 2015 Kia Optima stop lamp relay fuse keeps blowing

Tags: lights, third-brake-light

It’s the relay fuse 15 am one under the hood keeps blowing right when I put it in

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a short somewhere, so I would eliminate the easy stuff first:

1. remove the stop light bulbs, one at a time. Then if no improvement disconnect the 3rd brakelight if it has one.
2. disconnect the stop lamp switch - this checks the wire to the rear,

If it stll blows then it may be between the fuse and the brakeswitch which will be harder to find.

If you can, make a 5W sidelight bulb with two wires to take the place of the fuse - when it goes out you have found the fault and saves blowing so many fuses while finding the problem.